# Export Lotus Notes rich-text mime content into Word/Excel via Apache-POI

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, mime

I created a webpage and want to allow the users to export the content of the pages. For that I used the Apache-POI libs. That works fine for text. But how can I export mime content? If I change the rich-text properties to 'Store content as html/mime' (because I want to format the content in Notes and sometimes the content contains an image).
If that is not possible what are useable alternatives in a xpage?

The code below will be executed as a xAgent.

Thanks
Armin

```
importPackage(java.io);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.hwpf);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel);
importPackage(org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem);

var docID = sessionScope.contentUNID;
var nv:NotesView = database.getView("(allByKey)");
var doc:NotesDocument = nv.getDocumentByKey(docID, true);

var fs:POIFSFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("empty.doc"));
var wdoc:HWPFDocument = new HWPFDocument(fs);
var wdRange:Range = wdoc.getRange();

wdRange.insertBefore(doc.getItemValueString("title"));
wdRange.insertAfter(doc.getMIMEEntity("content")); !!!doesn'twork

var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
var pageResponse = extCont.getResponse();
var pageOutput = pageResponse.getOutputStream();

pageResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word");
pageResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
pageResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=export.doc");
wdoc.write(pageOutput);
pageOutput.flush();
pageOutput.close();

facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use methods of `MIMEEntity` class to get the content. For example `doc.getMIMEEntity("content").getContentAsText()`. For this to work you probably need to set `session.setConvertMIME(false)` before getting the doc.

Another way is to get it as as `RichTextItem` with `doc.getFirstItem("content")` and use the methods of `RichTextItem` class to get the content. In this case you would not set the `session.setConvertMIME(false)`.

Comment: Ok, I realized that I need the method of the MIMEEntity. If I used the getContentAsText I get "This is a multipart message in MIME format.". The code will be executed as a xAgent (xpage without rendering) so I am not able to set the session property (at least I am not aware of this). Sorry that I missed that information with the xAgent.

Comment: @ArminMandel Yes you can (and often have to) use session also when the XPage is not rendered.

Comment: @ArminMandel: You have to parse the whole MIME message, not only the first node.

Comment: Ok, got it. I parsed the mime entry and got the content. But it contains the formatting information (e.g. x</font><font size=3> </font><font size=2 face="sans-serif"><br>.... ). Encoding is 1726. So how can I de/en-code that to get the nice looking part?

Comment: @ArminMandel Try RichTextItem.getUnformattedText() or getFormattedText().